# How to Manage SQLite Database For Below Case

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I got one task as below

[image]

Above graph contains different cases which can be occur with the combination of two different selection.

In my application i need to put two drop-down boxes (I.E two spinners), from that two spinners user will select different values and i need to show that value as a result.

Now result after selecting two different spinners value is calculated like this , for example suppose from first spinner I am selecting `Benazepril` from row number 3 and `Amiloride hydrochloride` from row number 1, so this selection will give me result as a red symbol mention on graph, which has been marked with black cricle.

Now my question is i need to manage this entire thing on my `SQLite` Databse, Above description is just a graphical representation of logic, now i need to apply this logic at run time. I need to store all values And It's Combination result on my database. How to handle such situation?

Now Second query is after Selecting any case i need to show small graphical respresentation on my application for two different selection as below

[image]

So this is my query, I am not getting how to handle such situation, can any one give some nice guide for it?

Thanks

Comment: your second query is not clear to me. Are you looking for how to show the graphic? This depends from what language and/or SDK you use.

Comment: @sqlab Yes need to show graph but i guess that's not a big issue, i can manage it to work by adding layout run time, thanks for the time

Answer (score 2):

You could use a table like

```
create table interactions (
  substance1 ..
  substance2 ..
  interaction ..
)
```

where you store all combinations and can answer your first question

An alternative approach would be using bitmaps for every row and every type of interaction.Then you have to build your query bitmap according. Every bit stands for a crossing of substance1 with substance2. You have to define the position of substance2  at an other place or table.

```
create table interactions (
    substance
    bitmap
    interactiontype
    ....
```

Instead of the bitmap a string would do it too, where you use different chars for any possible  interaction type at the crosspoint like "0X00X000000100".

```
 create table interactions (
  substance ..
  crossreactions varchar( 
)
```

Comment: Yes i also tought like that and for that need to store all field pair value in db, Thanks for that, but if still any more feasible way i could find than i would like to do it else This is a solution

Comment: I added a second method to my answer

Comment: Thanks, But For second Answer storing bitmap for all cases is not feasible solution i think